# ngx datatable footer icons not displaying

Tags: angular6, ngx-datatable

Not able to display the ngx datatable default footer properly.
Its showing the footer like this
[image: ngxdatatable footer]

My code

```
    <ngx-datatable
            #table
            [columnMode]="'force'"
            [headerHeight]="50"
            [rowHeight]="'auto'"
            [footerHeight]="50"
            [count]="true"
            [limit]="4"
            [rows]="data"
        >
    <ngx-datatable-column [width]=10>
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <span class="circle" [ngClass]="{'red': row.alertCat == 'HIGH','yellow': row.alertCat == 'MEDIUM', 'green': row.alertCat == 'LOW'}"></span>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="ID" [width]=10>
                    <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                            <strong class="text-uppercase alertHeading">ID</strong>
                    </ng-template>
      <ng-template let-row="row">
        {{row.id}}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ngx-datatable>
```

Answer (score 5):

use `node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css` in your main `.scss file`:

```
"styles": [
    //  ...
    "node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css"
],
```

Comment: It worked for me i was trying to include this file at the component level, but it didn-t work, including it on the angular.json file on the "styles" worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, your footer classes are being overridden by other classes. Inspect them and you will know or provide your icons like from font-awesome.
For ex

```
.datatable-icon-left {
     content: @fa-var-chevron-left;
 }
```